# SVN backup on Linux

Tags: linux, backup, svn

I have SVN repository at /var/svn, and folder /var is backup incrementally everyday by the standard TSM backup. Do I still need to do the dump backup for SVN?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to SVN repos, which are generally very important and somewhat touchy... you can't be too careful.

I'd suggest having a routine svn dump and if the svn repo is even moderately active, I'd suggest an svn mirror via svn sync. A mirror will give you faster failover and recovery with less chance of data loss, assuming you're running the sync command every minute or so. Backing up svn specifically/separately and verifying those backups on occasion will save you a lot of headache some day.

Comment: Thanks, will create a dump for each working day so keep 7 past days in /var/backup, and the TMS backup will backup this folder as well. Should be good enough.

Comment: Sure.   don't forget to 'accept' an answer when you're happy, it'll prevent the question from lingering in the unanswered lists for ages.     and welcome to server fault.